# Dynamically position text within a td element of a table.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position text within a viewport so that as the user scrolls along the viewport the text in the column remains visible for as long as possible.  The issue is that the view port may be smaller than the width of the column in the table.  So I have something close to working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Deterus/6eU24/15/

```
$rowDiv.scroll(function (e) {
$headerDiv.css({
    left: -$rowDiv[0].scrollLeft + 'px'
});
var thresh = $('.peek').width();

$.leftofscreen("#lookInMe", ".peek", {
    threshold: thresh
}).removeClass("textAdjustTL").addClass("textAdjustTR");
$.rightofscreen("#lookInMe", ".peek", {
    threshold: thresh
}).removeClass("textAdjustTR").addClass("textAdjustTL");

$.inviewportCenter("#lookInMe", ".peek", {
    threshold: 0
}, thresh);
```

});

This is where I am able to add or manipulate the css needed to keep the row elements at the edge of the viewport. Currently the classes just align the text to the right or left and doesnt allow the sliding nature I need. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what exactly you want.. You just need some content to be always visible even when user scrolls..? what is the desired output from that fiddle?

Comment: The desired result would be that instead of the row text jumping to be right aligned as the user scrolls, it would scroll along with the edge of the view port until it met the next td.  Then the row 2 text would move along with the edge of the view port until row3 and so on. Does that make sense?